# Adding in a layer of password-check code into registration code

Tags: java, android

I currently have a project on Firebase, where I am trying to authenticate new users. Code is as follows.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email_registration) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password_registration))) {

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_registration, password_registration).addOnCompleteListener(Register.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to create account. Please check", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Account created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

What I would like to achieve is a level of simple password checking, and the code I came up with is as follows. The new variable, password_confirm is the second field for users to type in their password again.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email_registration) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password_registration))) {

                if (TextUtils.equals(password_registration, password_confirm)) {
                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_registration, password_registration).addOnCompleteListener(Register.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Failed to create account. Please check", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Account created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

However, I believe this logic does not work because when both if statements are fulfilled, then there is no reason for the authentication to not work (i.e the else statement at the end is of no use). I am also unable to think of any ideas to get this to work because the addOnCompleteListener and if-else statements have to be present.

I come from a Python background where we can just set the 2 if statements, then enable mAuth, and set other cases to "disable" mAuth. I'm at a loss and would appreciate some help here. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? I also can't spot these `else` branches you're referring to that might be be superfluous. I can think of other reasons for the registration to fail, like existing email address, invalid email address, too insecure password (I think firebase had something like this in place)

Comment: I meant the else statement right at the end